# Почему жадных душит жаба?

Tags: фразеология

"Жаба душит" говорят о тех, кому чего-то для кого-то жалко, а проще — о жадности. А почему жаба и почему душит? Пошло ли это от созвучия "жадность" и "жаба" (хотя созвучие в две буквы только), от старого названия стенокардии — "грудная жаба" или от чего-то еще?
К слову, на Востоке жаба всегда считалась символом денег.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Действительно тут имеется в виду "жаба" не биологическая. Но о том - чуть позже.

Сначала - о самой "медицинской" жабе. В отношении происхождения названия этой самой грудной жабы можно поспорить. Есть народные объяснения. Помимо того, что внешний вид больного якобы напоминает жабу (см. Людмилу), говорят еще и о его субъективных ощущениях. типа того, что на "грудь прыгает огромная жаба". Все это весьма сомнительно. Во-первых стенокардия не "душит",  а сдавливает (поскольку саму испытать Божьей милостью пока не довелось, говорю с чужих слов), а во вторых - и в главных - старое название стенокардии вторично. Есть еще просто "жаба", она же "горловая жаба" - обычная ангина. Вот она-то действительно в чем-то душит. 
Название же этой "жабы" вернее всего связано не с земноводным гадом, а с жабрами. Жаба в значении "горло", "рот" известно в ряде говоров.

Теперь самое интересное. Если я правильно понимаю, французское слово "жабо" на древнейшем уровне связано с этой самой жабой, но я в романских не силен, могу и наврать. Как бы то ни было, это "жабо" перекочевало в русский в значении "воротник" и породило **"жабо душит"**.
А далее, по одной из версий, которая мне лично вполне нравится, было обкатано народом до "жаба душит". Во всяком случае образ жадины, которому тесный воротник не дает дышать, вполне себе самодостаточен.
Тут, конечно, есть некоторые нестыковки, но из не более чем в "народной" этимологии.

Да, забыл. Есть еще диалектное слово жабот**а** - заботы, хлопоты, насущные дела. 
Тоже ведь вариант. Повседневные заботы так душат...

//------------------

Коли ответ принят. повторю, что не считаю эту версию единственной возможной. В ней есть нестыковки.
Но альтернативные и без того хорошо известны и тоже страдают слабой аргументацией.

Comment: ЖАБО -фр. jabot букв. зоб (у птицы). Версия имеет право на жизнь, но как это связано с жадностью? Это же жадных душит жаба! А воротник, по виду напоминавший зоб, должен всех душить. Да и ангина к жадности какое имеет отношение? А вот жадные и завистливые действительно переживают стресс и получают сердечную боль.И цвет лица становится зеленовато-серым при кислородном голодании - как у жабы.

Comment: >Версия имеет право на жизнь, но как это связано с жадностью? Это же жадных душит жаба!   
  
Простите, версия мне нравится именно, что она объясняет, связь с жадностью. Именно сдавливающий воротник - прямая аналогия с жадностью. Ни вдохнуть - не выдохнуть. Там масса других нестыковок, это да. Но смысл-то как раз объясняет прекрасно.

Вот какая связь у жадности с жабой (в любом значении) для меня загадка. Возможно, мы как-то очень по-разному представляем физическое проявление жадности. Я имею в виду мимику и жест, пластику тела и проч. Со стенокардией общего не вижу в любом случае.

Comment: А не может ли тут, как сказал автор вопроса, играть роль одинаковость первых слогов "ЖАба" и "ЖАдность"?

Comment: >играть роль одинаковость первых слогов "ЖАба" и "ЖАдность"?  
  
Если говорить о этимологии - вряд ли. Разве что какая-то "народная" ассоциация, вторичное переосмысление... Такое иногда случается, но редко.

Answer (score 8):

Думаю, всё же от старого медицинского названия"грудная жаба"-стенокардия.
Внезапные приступы боли за грудиной, в области сердца, вследствие недостаточности кровоснабжения сердечной мышцы часто вызываются  сужением сосудов из-за стресса или продолжительного переживания по поводу чего-либо.

А вот почему когда-то так стенокардию назвали - очень даже понятно: видела однажды приступ стенокардии у пожилой  полной женщины. Было очень страшно: она вся раздулась , как жаба, тяжело дышала и глаза навыкате, я думала, она умрёт, но ничего, отходили.

Answer (score 1):

У братьев Гримм есть сказка о том, как сын с женой пожалели дать старому отцу курицу. Она превратилась в жабу. Прыгнула сыну на лицо и приклеилась так, что ему было тяжело дышать. И убрать её не смогли. Так он и прожил остаток жизни с жабой на лице.

Comment: Интересно, конечно, но хорошо бы указать название сказки. А главное - какое это имеет отношение к вопросу?